# GULP SRC | Negatives not working as expected

Tags: gulp, src

I was trying to understand how gulp works, and particularly how to select files, so I ran some tests. But the results are not as they were supposed to be.

Could somebody please explain me why I get theses results and if it was the result expected.

Files set

```
assets
|-script01.js
|--sub01
   |-script02.js
   |-script03.js
|--sub02
   |-script04.js
   |--sub03
      |-script05.js
```

My aim was no get all files except all the sub02 folder. Pretty simple as it seemed :)

gulpfile.js

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');

exports.test01 = function() {
  return src(['assets/**/*', '!assets/sub02'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}
```

But the output was

```
// output
// |-script01.js
// |--sub01
//    |-script02.js
//    |-script03.js
// |--sub02
//    |-script04.js
//    |--sub03
//       |-script05.js
```

So I ran different tests like

```
exports.test02 = function() {
  return src(['assets/**/*', '!assets/sub02/*'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}
```

Which output is

```
output
|-script01.js
|--sub01
    |-script02.js
    |-script03.js
|--sub02
    |--sub03
       |-script05.js
```

Then I tried this

```
exports.test03 = function() {
  return src(['assets/**/*', '!assets/sub02/**/*'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}
```

Which logically results in

```
output
|-script01.js
|--sub01
   |-script02.js
   |-script03.js
|--sub02
```

And finally I understood how to accomplish what I wanted

```
exports.test04 = function() {
  return src(['assets/**/*', '!assets/sub02/**/*', '!assets/sub02'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}
```

Yay!

```
output
|-script01.js
|--sub01
   |-script02.js
   |-script03.js
```

But regarding the doc (of gulp, https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs), I should be able to accomplish Test 01

```
exports.test05 = function() {
  return src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}
// Result : all directories and their .js files in output
// including node_mudules ones.
```

And here's a bonus question. Running the tests, I tried this. But didn't work neither. Why ?

```
// --- BONUS QUESTION
exports.bonus = function() {
  return src(['assets/**/*', '!assets/sub02/**/*', 'assets/sub02/script04.js'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}

output
|-script01.js
|--sub01
   |-script02.js
   |-script03.js
|--sub02
* script04.js missing :( *
```

If you want to test it quickly :

```
mkdir -p assets assets/sub01 assets/sub02/sub03 output;

touch assets/script01.js assets/sub01/script02.js assets/sub01/script03.js assets/sub02/script04.js assets/sub02/sub03/script05.js
```

Many thanks in advance !

---

### EDIT

After further investigation, this works to

```
exports.test01 = function() {
  return src(['assets/**/*.js', '!assets/sub02/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(dest('output/'))
}

// output
// |-script01.js
// |--sub01
//    |-script02.js
//    |-script03.js
```

So as I understand it, ** includes assets/sub02 folder as folder.
So dest copies the folder as folder, except if all the files first selected in src first globs are negated. Any thoughts ?